# How to implement custom buffer types with File Stream encapsulation C++

Tags: c++, buffer

[Set Buffer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubsetbuf)

Basically, it boils down to whether or not I can initialize a `std::basic_fstream` with a custom buffer. I wanted to use protected inheritance for the `std::basic_streambuf` so I had access to the get area pointers. Then simply pass my new object to the `basic_fstream` so it is used instead of the default buffers.

Use this:

```
#include <streambuf>
class strbuffer : protected std::streambuf {
public:
  strbuffer();
  char_type* operator+(unsigned int slots);
  char_type* cur;
  char_type* beg;
  char_type* eob;
};

strbuffer::strbuffer() : std::streambuf() {
  cur = strbuffer::gptr();
  beg = strbuffer::eback();
  eob = strbuffer::egptr();
}

// returns val of cur
std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char>>::char_type* strbuffer::operator+(unsigned int slots) {
  int_type t;
  for (int i = 0; i < slots; i++)
    t = this->sbumpc();
  return new char_type(t);
}
```

With something like:

```
class fstream0 : public std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char>> {
public:
  fstream0();
  void fInit();
  void format();
  bool connectFile(std::string fname);
  bool connectFile(std::string path, std::string fname);
  void closeFile();
  std::ios_base::iostate get8(std::string& out); //32 bit size estimation?
  }
```

Where the constructor of `fstream0` would take an argument that is a `stream_buf` (casting?) object:

```
    fstream0::fstream0(arg) : std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char>>() {
// create bare bones file stream
// buffer is provided, constructor overloaded with support for many file types
// char*, std::array, etc...
      strBuf = fstream0::rdbuf();
      fBuf = fstream0::rdbuf();
    }
```

Do I have to use `pubsetbuf` to write over already initialized buffers in order to use many different data types for my custom buffer? Including one that inherits from `std::streambuf`?

Comment: `std::basic_streambuf` is meant to be derived and used by derived implemenations that override certain characteristics of the stream device

Comment: That constructor isn't public, so it isn't callable in this code.

Comment: `std::basic_streambuf` is the interface used to implement how characters are read or written. The default implementation of all functions just causes failures. You want to derive from it and implement `underflow()` (for input streams) and/or `overflow()` (for output streams). There are plenty of example how that is done.

Comment: I've inherited in my other proj. `class strbuffer : protected std::streambuf`, I need to compose this class with my other inherited class `class fstream0 : public std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char>>` but the base class constructor wants an std::streambuffer object and not my derived strbuffer object. I'm looking into replacing the default buffers after I create my file stream.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik, I've edited my question and I do not believe it is a duplicate as I READ the post you've submitted as its duplicate prior to my original post. Please review my edit.